# objective-c UIAlert button not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am a newbie at objective-c and I have an UIAlert that is inside a function like so:

```
- (void)loadJSON
{

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Announcement" message: @"No Connection" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; [alert release];
        });
    } else {
      //some code
    }
}
```

and when the user clicks the OK button this function should fire up to recall the loadJSON function? (atleast I think so)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self loadJSON];
}
```

My end goal here is if there is no internet connection, display UIAlert, user sees message, clicks okay, if still no internet connection, display alert. I disconnected from the internet and the alert message only appears once.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not assigned delegate for alertView.

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Announcement" 
                                                    message: @"No Connection" 
                                                   delegate: self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
```

Comment: Yes I was having trouble with this.  Make sure it is " delegate: self" I had "delegate: nil" and nothing was happening. Thanks Gururaj.T